# Using Coded UI to Simulate File Drag and Drop Operation

Tags: c#, testing, coded-ui-tests

I have a WinForm application which is a drop target for files and folders. I'd like to use Coded UI to have an automated tests that verifies the application does what I think it should do when files were dropped on it.

I used the Coded UI recorder to record this operation, but I need to generalize it and make it work on CI server. So I basically want to init the test with some pre-setup file paths (the files can be created as part of the test setup), and then just trigger the drop event passing in the paths to those files on the file system.

Coded UI records the test but produces a test like:

```
WinListItem uIContactcshtmlListItem = this.UIProgramManagerWindow.UIDesktopList.UIContactcshtmlListItem;
WinText uIDragDropFilesHereText = this.UIMyApp.UIDragDropFilesHereWindow.UIDragDropFilesHereText;
uIDragDropFilesHereText.EnsureClickable(new Point(84, 13));
Mouse.StartDragging(uIContactcshtmlListItem, new Point(17, 35));
Mouse.StopDragging(uIDragDropFilesHereText, new Point(84, 13));
```

The "uIContactcshtmlListItem" appears to represent the source files I dropped. (A contacts.cs file happens to be one of the things I dragged/dropped during the recording.) I want to replace this with just some file paths, but this appears to essentially be a list item type control from Explorer.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want? Perhaps by creating a WinListItem in the code manually?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it (requires some coding):

Record opening a windows explorer, writing in the address bar and pressing enter. Then record dragging a file to your application (drag it by its icon to avoid future frustrations). Add your assertions. Record closing the windows explorer. These should be four methods plus the assertions: open explorer, set address, drag file, close explorer.

Now you have your base methods. Call the method that opens the explorer first then loop thru your input file paths. In the loop: set the parameters for the 'set address' and 'drag files' methods for the file (you can check the current directory in the explorer and only call 'set address' if needed) and the name search property for the ListItem UIControl (the control/file you want to drag). Call Find() on the ListItem/Image UIControl or set AlwaysSearch for this control in the UIMap (you need this because we are reusing a UIControl here which is cached on a previous object) then call the 'drag file' method. Then check your assertions.

Finally call the 'close explorer' method. You will probably have to tweak around a bit in the UIMap to make things work properly (change search properties and stuff).

Of course this is not the only way to do it, not the best either but might be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Change the search parameter

```
WinListItem uIContactcshtmlListItem = this.UIProgramManagerWindow.UIDesktopList.UIContactcshtmlListItem;

WinText uIDragDropFilesHereText = this.UIMyApp.UIDragDropFilesHereWindow.UIDragDropFilesHereText;

uIContactcshtmlListItem.SearchProperties.Remove(UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name);
uIContactcshtmlListItem.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "ItemName" or variable);
or uIContactcshtmlListItem.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "PartOfTheName", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);


uIDragDropFilesHereText.EnsureClickable(new Point(84, 13));

Mouse.StartDragging(uIContactcshtmlListItem, new Point(17, 35));
Mouse.StopDragging(uIDragDropFilesHereText, new Point(84, 13));
```